# Is it possible to host angular 8 build copy and Slim/Lumen PHP Framework on same port to avoid CORS issue in apache server

Tags: angular, laravel, slim, lumen

I would like to host angular UI and Slim/Lumen framework on same port without getting CORS issue.Please help me out.thanks

Comment: You can [enable CORS](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/cookbook/enable-cors.html) in Slim framework in development environment. When you build Angular for production, CORS will not be an issue since both frontend and backend will be hosted in the same domain.

Comment: I would like to have on same port and same domain

Comment: CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) is about cross-origin requests. Say, your homepage is `http://example.com` and Slim/Lumen API endpoint for posts would be `http://example.com/api/posts`. Then you can easily make a request using Angular to `/api/posts` without worrying about CORS.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the steps to be performed for this setup in server